# Protobuf version difference in generated code for std::string in oneof

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I want to degrade my protobuf version from 3.17.0 to 3.12.0, But I get a problem. For example:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Foo {
  optional int32 a = 1;
}

message Test {
  oneof value {
    string str = 1;
    Foo foo = 2;
  }
}
```

For this protofile, I compile it with protoc(3.17.0), I get a utility method in generated `Test` class to check if `str` is set in the oneof field:

```
  // from generated test.pb.h
  // string str = 1;
  bool has_str() const;
  private:
  bool _internal_has_str() const;
  public:
  void clear_str();
  // ...
```

But when I use protoc(3.12.0) to compile it and set the optional flag:

```
./protoc test.proto --cpp_out=./ --experimental_allow_proto3_optional
```

I got the generated code:

```
  // string str = 1;
  private:
  bool _internal_has_str() const;
  public:
  void clear_str();
```

So ,`has_str` doesn't exist anymore. Does anybody know why? Thanks!

PS:
`has_foo` will always exist.

Comment: Perhaps it's just not implemented correctly in 3.12.0, it is marked as experimental and requires a additional flag after all.

Comment: @Kaldrr If that's true, I can't believe it is google's product.

Answer (score 0):

The has accessors in C++ for oneof fields were added in [3.15](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.15.0):

> Now Proto3 Oneof fields have "has" methods for checking their presence in
> C++.

This is *coincidentally* the same version that includes non-experimental proto3 optional support:

> Optional fields for proto3 are enabled by default, and no longer require
> the --experimental_allow_proto3_optional flag.

Prior to that version, one can [use the generated `_case()` function](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated#oneof) to detect which oneof field is set.